# Looking for a tool to expand shortened urls

Tags: browser-addons, url-shortening

The interwebs seem to be infested with shortened urls (Twitter I'm looking at you). I'm always reluctant to click these as it is a leap into the unknown. Are there any browser plugins or Greasemonkey scripts that will auto-expand the shortened URL or give me a tooltip with the resolved target?

I've seen [LongUrl.org](http://longurl.org/), which has an API I could use to roll my own, but I'd like to avoid the effort if this is a solved problem.

Comment: Does this not have both http://longurl.org/tools ?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching I found this article on a [Greasemonkey script](http://beerpla.net/2009/03/17/twitter-autocomplete-auto-url-expansion-auto-url-shortener-auto-pagination-rt-button-nested-replies-inline-media-embed-search-tabs-and-more/) that expands URLs and more:

Before:
[image: before screenshot]

After:
[image: after screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Not a general answer but if you're following Twitter, [Feeddemon](http://feeddemon.com/) (available, but discontinued in 2013) has support for this, it will show a tooltip with the complete url.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody already did the work for you on Firefox : [LongURL Mobile Expander](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/32115) :

> You should always know where a link
> takes you before clicking on it.
> Services like TinyURL.com make that
> difficult. LongURL Mobile Expander
> uses the LongURL.org web services to
> let you know where shortened links
> *really* go.

Not all the comments are positive, though.

[image]

You can also look at [Long URL Please](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9549)

> Short urls (eg http://tinyurl.###/123)
> simply redirect to some other page on
> the internet - you can't tell what
> website they link to by looking at the
> link. This plugin fixes this by
> transparently replacing any of these
> links when every web page loads.
>
> Uses the api provided by
> http://www.longurlplease.com to
> determine where short urls actually
> link to.

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins and GM scripts to do this if you are using Firefox (I don't know about other browsers off the top of my head). https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13140 is the first one that came up in a  quick search.