# Is there a Firefox addon to show unshortened URLs in a tooltip?

Tags: browser-addons, url-shortening

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a tool to expand shortened urls](https://superuser.com/questions/81367/looking-for-a-tool-to-expand-shortened-urls)

I need a FF addon to do something like [Unshorten](http://www.unshorten.com) and present the real URL in a tooltip. The addon should be FF3.6 compatible. Does anyone know if there is such an addon out there?

Comment: There are 2 answers which suit your needs at --> [Looking for a tool to expand shortened urls](http://superuser.com/questions/81367/looking-for-a-tool-to-expand-shortened-urls)

Comment: The answers to that question DO NOT suit my needs. None of them is Firefox 3.6 compatible!